# Laravel calendar scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make an calendar scheduler for student teacher for their future lessons together.
I'm trying to add day, time and DATE(most important). Right now I added day and time in each of their following meetings. For ex. every Monday at 08:00 and every Wednesday at 10:00. But what I cannot add is Date . Here is some of my coding.

```
$student = Auth::user()->student;

    $teacher = Teacher::where('id',$id)->first();

     $lessons = $request->lessons_booked;
     $times = $request->times;
     $timesArrLength = count($times);
     $stuTeachArr = array();
     for($i = 1;$i<= $lessons;$i++){
       $studentTeacher = StudentTeacher::create([
            'student_id' => $student->id,
            'teacher_id' => $teacher->id,
            'subject_id' => $request->subject_id,
            'place_of_tutoring_id' => $request->place_of_tutoring_id,
            'lessons_booked' => $lessons,
            'lesson_nr' => $i,
            'time_id' => $times[($i-1) % $timesArrLength]['id'],
            'day' => $times[($i-1) % $timesArrLength]['day'],
            'date' => '2021-01-01', // add date here
            'lessons_left' => $request->lessons_booked - $i,
            'status' => 'active'
       ]);
       array_push($stuTeachArr,$studentTeacher);
     }
        
        // $stuTeachArr['booked_teacher'] = $studentTeacher;

     return $stuTeachArr;
```

What I want is to add DATE for every lesson that will happen from now until they finish with their lessons(For ex. every Monday and every Wednesday as mentioned before).
Any suggestion to change the way I'm doing would be welcomed.

Comment: whats the issue or error, request not having date?

Comment: there is no error, its more about how to implement a piece of code!

Comment: what you have shown in the code is just saving a bunch of values you are saving using your model, but it does not make clear what you want to do, please make clear what the current code does for you & what is your desired output

Comment: by calender how are you implementing it